# Need to be Able to Access Common.php from any Directory

Tags: php

```
<div id="phpbbBox"><?php

define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = './forum/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx); 




// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();


if($user->data['is_registered'])
{

    echo "Hello " . "<a href=\"http://cgoava.com/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&un=" . $user->data['username'] . "\">" . $user->data['username'] . "</a>"; //User is already logged in
    echo "<br /> You have " . "<a href=\"http://cgoava.com/forum/ucp.php?i=pm&folder=inbox\">" . $user->data['user_new_privmsg'] . " new PM!</a> ";
    echo "<br /> Last visit: " . $user->format_date($user->data['session_last_visit']);

}
else if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $username = request_var('username', '', true);
    $password = request_var('password', '', true);
    $autologin = (!empty($_POST['autologin'])) ? true : false;

    $result = $auth->login($username, $password, $autologin);

    if ($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS)
    {
        //User was successfully logged into phpBB


        // append/replace SID
        $redirect = reapply_sid($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    meta_refresh(0, $redirect);
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    location.reload();
    </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Bad Login ' . $username; //User's login failed
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="username" size="10">
        <input type="password" name="password" size="10"><br />
         Remember Me?: <input type="checkbox" name="autologin">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="login">
        </form>';
}
?></div>
```

This all works on the: www.example.com/page.php

Yet, it does not work on the: www.example.com/ex/page2.php, or www.example.com/ex/word/page3.php

Working to access where common.php is from any directory that I'm in, yet, it also needs to be an authorized access, so a simple $_SERVER include hasn't been working.

When I try to make the entire thing its own include, it still does not work. The main goal was to get all of this code in one of the core includes, to display in the menu on every page.

Login works on the one page. I need both the login and the post-login code to be usable on every page of the site (40+ page site).
I've used 2 levels of includes to structure the site.

Comment: Nothing works better than going from document root down. `$phpbb_root_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'path/to/forum/';`

Answer (score 0):

as it works at www.example.com/page.php and not at deeper directories, it looks like your forum directory is at `/forum` and not at `./forum`
so change

```
$phpbb_root_path = './forum/';
```

to

```
$phpbb_root_path = '/forum/';
```

(./ is the current directory so it is looking for common.php in www.example.com/ex/forum/common.php)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use relative paths in this case. If you make `$phpbb_root_path` an absolute path, then building paths from that variable will work fine.

Try:

```
$phpbb_root_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/to/forum/';
```